# logout function don't work in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization

The logout function is not working in my app, i.e. after logging out, the functions are still logged in without authentication, but these functions are authorize and need to reauthenticate. My project is written with asp.net Core v5 :please help me
codes in Startup.cs:

```
namespace ERP
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            #region Authenication
            services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddCookie("ProvinceArea", options =>
             {
                 options.Cookie.Name = "ProvinceArea";
                 options.LoginPath = "/PLogin";
                 options.LogoutPath = "/PLogout";
                 options.ExpireTimeSpan =TimeSpan.FromHours(12);
             }).AddCookie("CountyArea", options =>
             {
                 options.Cookie.Name = "CountyArea";
                 options.LoginPath = "/CLogin";
                 options.LogoutPath = "/CLogout";
                 options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(12);
             }).AddCookie("DistrictArea", options =>
             {
                 options.Cookie.Name = "DistrictArea";
                 options.LoginPath = "/DLogin";
                 options.LogoutPath = "/DLogout";
                 options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(12);
             });


            #endregion

            #region Db Context

            services.AddDbContext<ERPContext>(options =>
                { options.UseSqlServer("Data Source =.;Initial Catalog=ERP_DB;Integrated Security=true"); });

            #endregion

            #region IOC
            services.AddTransient<IManagementService, ManagementService>();
            #endregion 


        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {


            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "areas",
                pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
             );
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

codes in login and logout functions:

```
[Route("PLogin")]
        public IActionResult PLogin()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("PLogin")]
        public IActionResult PLogin(LoginViewModel login)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(login);
            }

            var user = _ManagementService.PLoginUser(login);
            if (user != null)
            {
                var claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,user.nationalCode.ToString()),
                        new Claim("nationalCode",user.nationalCode.ToString()),
                        new Claim("fName",user.fName.ToString()),
                        new Claim("lName",user.lName.ToString()),
                        new Claim("department",user.department.ToString()),
                        new Claim("role",user.role.ToString())
                    };

                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

                HttpContext.SignInAsync("ProvinceArea", principal);

                ViewBag.IsSuccess = true;
                return View(login);
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("nationalCode", "کاربری با مشخصات وارد شده یافت نشد");
            return View(login);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Logout
        //تابع خروج
        [Route("PLogout")]
        public IActionResult PLogout()
        {
            HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            return Redirect("/PLogin");
        }
        #endregion
```

codes in authorize:

```
namespace ERP.Areas.ProvinceArea.Controllers
{ 
    [Area("ProvinceArea")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "ProvinceArea")]

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
```

Comment: Hi try using HttpContext.Session.Clear();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed a wrong scheme into `HttpContext.SignOutAsync()` method.

Try modify `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` to `"ProvinceArea"`

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpContext.Session.Clear();
```

But in your startup.cs I cant't see

```
UseSession();
```

By using sessions in ASP.NET Core,
it allows application to store data in a session and retrieve it later.
Session is stored on the server side and a session ID is sent to the client in a cookie.

Comment: I don't using session in my project